# What is the auth_user.password field format in web2py

Tags: web2py

I see the `auth_user.password` is kept in the following format:
`pbkdf2(1000,20,sha512)$<xxx>$<yyy>`

what are `<xxx>` and `<yyy>`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `<xxx>` is 16 hex-encoded characters of salt, `<yyy>` is the hash, encoded to hex and truncated at 40 characters

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `<xxx>` is the salt and `<yyy>` is the password hash.